# How do I get the workspace directory at runtime in a Bazel go_test

Tags: go, bazel, bazel-rules

I'm using the `go_test` rule from [rule_go](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/docs/go/core/rules.md#go_test) in Bazel, and I'd like to access the workspace directory at runtime. I can't find it in the environment variables, and `$PWD` is the temp sandbox directory. How can I access this variable? Ideally, it's something I can pass into my rule and not a command-line argument to `bazel test` so that I don't have to write it out every time.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use the `data` attribute to declare files that you want to access at runtime. The docs for go_test.data 
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/docs/go/core/rules.md#go_test-data

point to this library 
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/go/tools/bazel

for conveniently accessing data dependencies.